# const-correctness of data-accessor types - better solution?

Tags: c++, templates, constants, const-correctness

I'm working on a image-class which makes it possible to work with images with different pixel layouts (RGB, RGBA, Gray, Bayer, ...). To access a pixel it's possible to call `image.at<PixelType>(x,y)` which returns an "Accessor". The concrete Accessor-implementation is dependent on the template argument. But now i've ran into some issues regarding const correctness.

Here is a very dumbed down implementation which hopefully makes it apparent:

```
template<bool constAccessor>
class Accessor {
public:
    typedef typename boost::mpl::if_c<constAccessor, const int, int>::type DataType;

    Accessor(DataType& data) 
    :data(data) {
    }

    Accessor(Accessor<false>& other) 
    : data(other.data) {
    }

    DataType& data;
};


class Image {
public:
    Accessor<false> at(unsigned int x, unsigned int y) {
        return Accessor<false>(data);
    }
    Accessor<true> at(unsigned int x, unsigned int y) const {
        return Accessor<true>(data);
    }

private:
    int data;
};

int main() {
    Image img;
    const Image& cimg = img;

    // get accessor which is non-const
    Accessor<false> a1 = img.at(0, 0); 

    // get a accessor which is const...
    Accessor<true> a2 = a1;
    // ... modifying a value results in an error
    a2.data = 42;

    // try to convert a accessor which is const to a non-const version
    // ... results in an error
    Accessor<false> a3 = a2;

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see there is a non-const and a const implementation of the `at` method. Depending on the constness the template argument of the accessor is set to `true` or `false`. But now i've got two different types (const and non-const) per accessor/pixel type which makes it necessary to write a conversion constructor because otherwise the test-cases shown in the `main()` function wouldn't work.

Now the question is:
Is there a better way to achieve this? It feels kind of bad to use a template argument as const indicator. It would be much nicer to just use `Accessor` and `const Accessor`. On the other hand this is similar to what the std-library does with `::iterator` and `::const_iterator`. 
Anyone has some experience with such situations?

Comment: You can do something similar to what the standard containers does with iterators, in that it has two different iterators: `iterator` and `const_iterator`, forcing the programmer to think about what iterator to use. Unfortunately the programmers seldom think about it, and use normal `iterator` even when `const_iterator` would be best.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I've tried to clarify that i think that my approach is similar to the one of the std library. The questsion is if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can (over-)generalise your parameter from having the two boolean states to any value type instead:

```
template<typename Value>
class Accessor {
public:    
    Accessor(Value& data) 
        : data(data)
    {}

    template<typename T, EnableIf<std::is_convertible<T&, Value&>>...>
    Accessor(Accessor<T> const& other)
        : data(other.data)
    {}

    Value& data;
};
```

Obviously this isn’t any different than what you have, except under another guise: instead of `Accessor<false>` and `Accessor<true>`, you have `Accessor<DataType>` and `Accessor<DataType const>`.

The benefit is familiarity: all of e.g. `std::unique_ptr<T>`, `std::shared_ptr<T>`, `std::reference_wrapper<T>` (and even `T*`) behave the same way. In particular, this famialiarity should hopefully extend to compiler errors about a lack of conversion from `Accessor<DataType const>` to `Accessor<DataType>`, much like you can’t convert from `int const*` to `int*`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - especially the second paragraph made it clear that this behavior isn't that untypical